# Package loading causing error when deploying Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am getting an error when trying to deploy a Shiny app. I had previously been able to deploy the same app successfully. I believe it has to do with the packages I am loading but I am having a hard time troubleshooting which ones. I think it has to do with a couple of the packages and I think I've identified that colorspace is cause an issue. When I remove colorspace I am getting the same error so I think it may be multiple packages.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(readxl) #good
library(ggplot2) #good
library(dplyr) #good
library(stringr) #good
library(tidyr) #good
library(magrittr) #good
library(lubridate) #good
library(openxlsx) #good
library(scales) # good
library(colorspace) # bad
library(shiny) # good
library(curl) # good
library(openxlsx) # good
library(ggthemes) # unsure
library(leaflet) # unsure
library(shinythemes) # unsure
library(showtext) # unsure

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

deployApp.R

```
library(rsconnect)
deployApp(appName = "test2")
```

And here is the long error:

> deployApp(appName = "test2")
>   Preparing to deploy application...DONE
>   Uploading bundle for application: 1002337...DONE
>   Deploying bundle: 2183704 for application: 1002337 ...
>   Waiting for task: 625897405
>     building: Parsing manifest
>     building: Building image: 2303409
>     building: Installing system dependencies
>     building: Fetching packages
>     building: Installing packages
>     building: Installing files
>     building: Pushing image: 2303409
>
> ########################## Begin Task Log ################################

[2019-06-27T19:32:38.644208763+0000] Execute script: packages/build/sys.sh
+ set -e
+ apt-get update -qq
+ apt-get install -y libapparmor-dev
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapparmor1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapparmor-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libapparmor1
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 99 not upgraded.
Need to get 97.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 230 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapparmor1 amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11 [29.5 kB]
Get:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libapparmor-dev amd64 2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11 [67.8 kB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 97.3 kB in 0s (7814 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 119344 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapparmor1_2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapparmor1:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11) over (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.10) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Setting up libapparmor1:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapparmor-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 119344 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapparmor-dev_2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapparmor-dev:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up libapparmor-dev:amd64 (2.10.95-0ubuntu2.11) ...
[2019-06-27T19:32:46.867741305+0000] Installing R package: withr (2.1.2)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜withrâ€™ ...
* DONE (withr)
[2019-06-27T19:32:47.177306610+0000] Installing R package: viridisLite (0.3.0)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜viridisLiteâ€™ ...
* DONE (viridisLite)
[2019-06-27T19:32:47.420665470+0000] Installing R package: crayon (1.3.4)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜crayonâ€™ ...
* DONE (crayon)
[2019-06-27T19:32:47.701859695+0000] Installing R package: zeallot (0.1.0)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜zeallotâ€™ ...
* DONE (zeallot)
[2019-06-27T19:32:47.936696726+0000] Installing R package: xtable (1.8-4)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜xtableâ€™ ...
* DONE (xtable)
[2019-06-27T19:32:48.197319585+0000] Installing R package: magrittr (1.5)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜magrittrâ€™ ...
* DONE (magrittr)
[2019-06-27T19:32:48.432917932+0000] Installing R package: labeling (0.3)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜labelingâ€™ ...
* DONE (labeling)
[2019-06-27T19:32:48.644273152+0000] Installing R package: rlang (0.4.0)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜rlangâ€™ ...
* DONE (rlang)
[2019-06-27T19:32:48.944480920+0000] Installing R package: stringi (1.4.3)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜stringiâ€™ ...
* DONE (stringi)
[2019-06-27T19:32:49.394737083+0000] Installing R package: rematch (1.0.1)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜rematchâ€™ ...
* DONE (rematch)
[2019-06-27T19:32:49.608705910+0000] Installing R package: purrr (0.3.2)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜purrrâ€™ ...
* DONE (purrr)
[2019-06-27T19:32:49.884405044+0000] Installing R package: plogr (0.2.0)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜plogrâ€™ ...
* DONE (plogr)
[2019-06-27T19:32:50.151117758+0000] Installing R package: mime (0.7)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜mimeâ€™ ...
* DONE (mime)
[2019-06-27T19:32:50.380404050+0000] Installing R package: sys (3.2)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜sysâ€™ ...
* DONE (sys)
[2019-06-27T19:32:50.623448406+0000] Installing R package: fansi (0.4.0)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜fansiâ€™ ...
* DONE (fansi)
[2019-06-27T19:32:50.880863199+0000] Installing R package: packrat (0.5.0)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜packratâ€™ ...
* DONE (packrat)
[2019-06-27T19:32:51.153169848+0000] Installing R package: utf8 (1.1.4)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜utf8â€™ ...
* DONE (utf8)
[2019-06-27T19:32:51.417330005+0000] Installing R package: sourcetools (0.1.7)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜sourcetoolsâ€™ ...
* DONE (sourcetools)
[2019-06-27T19:32:51.706764719+0000] Installing R package: gtable (0.3.0)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜gtableâ€™ ...
* DONE (gtable)
[2019-06-27T19:32:52.003780539+0000] Installing R package: R6 (2.4.0)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜R6â€™ ...
* DONE (R6)
[2019-06-27T19:32:52.226633826+0000] Installing R package: RColorBrewer (1.1-2)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜RColorBrewerâ€™ ...
* DONE (RColorBrewer)
[2019-06-27T19:32:52.446557961+0000] Installing R package: lattice (0.20-38)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜latticeâ€™ ...
* DONE (lattice)
[2019-06-27T19:32:52.764007778+0000] Installing R package: nlme (3.1-139)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜nlmeâ€™ ...
* DONE (nlme)
[2019-06-27T19:32:53.283749888+0000] Installing R package: MASS (7.3-51.1)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜MASSâ€™ ...
* DONE (MASS)
[2019-06-27T19:32:53.616860274+0000] Installing R package: yaml (2.2.0)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜yamlâ€™ ...
* DONE (yaml)
[2019-06-27T19:32:53.922424843+0000] Installing R package: backports (1.1.4)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜backportsâ€™ ...
* DONE (backports)
[2019-06-27T19:32:54.307518695+0000] Installing R package: pkgconfig (2.0.2)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* installing *binary* package â€˜pkgconfigâ€™ ...
* DONE (pkgconfig)
[2019-06-27T19:32:54.563268370+0000] Installing R package: hms (0.4.2)
* installing to library â€˜/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/libraryâ€™
* insta################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 625897406 error: Unhandled Exception: HTTP 599: Timeout during request

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. I am using SASS and bootstrap to modify my apps CSS. In order to deploy the app you need to move all the r files and your final .css file to a new folder.

Otherwise, when you go to deploy your app, it fails on the "installing files" section. I guess the deploy cannot recognize the .json and .sass files etc.